# python package installation error while creating a webjob in azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-keyvault, azure-python-sdk

> i am creating a webjob which has following python dependencies(azure-storage-blob==12.8.1,azure) along with other dependencies, the problem is here that my code is getting stuck at below from almost 3-4 hours only.

```
Dowenloading azure_common-1.1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl(7.9kb)
pip is looking at multiple versions of azure-core to determine which version is compatible 
with other requirements. This could take a while.
[08/12/2021 19:55:54 > d827c9: INFO] INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to 
provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to  
abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what 
happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
```

> The thing is that if i installed specific version of azure then its not compatible with azure-storage-blob and its throwing error at importing blob storage and if f didnt install azure or other version of azure which is not compatible with azure-storage-blob==12.8.1 and throwing below error :

```
 from azure.keyvault import KeyVaultAuthentication, KeyVaultClient
 ImportError: cannot import name 'KeyVaultAuthentication'
```

> does anyone know how to install python packages while creating azure webjob and also solution to overcome this issue
>
> i have another question related to a triggered webjob , so suppose if i installed packages successfully so every time it runs whether it will install all the packages ever ytime or it will do only at first hit and saved packages in env

Answer (score 1):

Check what the dependency tree looks like locally by running `pip freeze` and then provide the strict versions to prevent the dependency resolution timeouts.